# Euclidean geometry problem with difficult circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $AB=5$, $AC=6$ and $BC=7$ and $O$ be the circle passing through the incenter, circumcenter and orthocenter of $ABC$.

$E$ and $F$ are points on circle $O$ such that $AE$ and $AF$ are tangent to $O$.

$\angle FAE$ is equal to $\displaystyle\frac{a \pi}{b}$ for positive integers $a,b$ with $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)=1$.

> What is $a+b$?

Note: For this problem we are working in Euclidean Geometry.

[image]

Comment: Try using geogebra to make a very accurate diagram. It will help to get the points in the right places on the diagram.

Comment: Coordinate geometry? Ugly but works

Comment: Which contest proposed such horrible problem? I am not even sure $\widehat{FAE}$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Upvote for this problem but downvote for no image. Anyway, as @JackD'Aurizio's comment, how can we know that $\angle FAE$ has the form $\frac{a\pi}{b}$.

Comment: Using co-ordinate geometry, if you get the co-ordinates of $A$ and $O$ and the radius $r$ of $O$ then $r^2+|EA|^2=|OA|^2$ so $(1/2)\angle FAE=\angle OAE= \sin^{-1}(r/|OA|).$

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Here's the GeoGebra diagram you ordered. Enjoy!

Comment: -1 For being a problem-statement-question with a dumb title. Someone let me know if the former problem is ever mitigated and I'll reverse it.

Comment: @rschwieb The title is the original one. I didn't modify it. Maybe I should, but I don't have any good ideas.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin It's debatable if modifying the title is a good idea. On one hand I commend you for improving a bad post. On the other hand I don't want to see mediocre posters enabled by the hard work of others. The best case scenario is that this person can learn to improve their own posts. Hopefully by seeing your example they will be inspired. I just hope you don't burn out before doing these good deeds :)

Comment: @GAVD According to my GeoGebra construct, the angle is $159.66177670151285^{\circ}$, which means $\frac{a}b$ might be one of these: $\{\frac45,\, \frac89,\, \frac{39}{44},\, \frac{55}{62},\, \frac{157}{177},\, \frac{997}{1124},\, \frac{3619}{4080},\, \frac{5927}{6682},\,
\frac{22554}{25427},\, \frac{39181}{44172},\, \frac{296821}{334631},\, \frac{1047187}{1180581},\, \frac{2430376}{2739965}\}$, as per Mathematica code `Table[Rationalize[#, 10^(-k)], {k, 13}] &`

Comment: @rschwieb I have changed the title.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin: Sorry for late answer. As I know, we have $\sin \angle FAE = \frac{16\sqrt{71610}}{12319}$, as same as Geogebra result. But I cannot figure it out as the question.